# preorder traversal of binary tree on f#

Tags: function, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, binary-tree

I am writing a function which takes a tree t1 and returns a string with all numbers stored in t1 (preoder transversal) seperated by whitespaces.

For example:

```
convertToStr( Node (Node (Node (Empty, 6, Empty), 2, Empty), 
5, Node (Empty, 0, Node (Empty, 1, Empty))) )
```

would give me

"5 2 6 0 1"

```
let rec convertToStr t1 =
 match t1 with
  | Node(E, v, E) -> String(v)
  | Node(E, v, w) -> converToStr(w)
  | Node(u, v, E) -> convertToStr(u)
  | Node(u, v, w) -> String(v) + convertToStr(u) + convertToStr(w)
```

I am still not getting the desired output. I am having trouble printing the right subtree. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your second and third cases fail to print `v`.  The most straightforward fix is to remedy that.